# ¿Cómo se puede obtener un acumulado hasta el mes anterior?

Tags: mysql

Se me ha presentado un problema con un código que tenia pero al cambiar de año al 2019, no me da la información que requiero.

Tengo dos columnas por separado en donde están el año y el mes, ambas de liquidación de unos intereses. Requiero tener un acumulado hasta el mes inmediatamente anterior al periodo consultado, es decir, si estoy en enero de 2019 debe darme un valor acumulado a diciembre de 2018, pero la consulta no me esta funcionando; le estuve haciendo varios cambios pero no me da, **¿qué puedo tener mal?**

Acá les dejo la consulta:

```
SELECT dlin_codcli, dlin_anoliq, dlin_mesliq, SUM(IFNULL(dlin_valint, 0)) AS dlin_valint
    FROM coo_detintaportes
        WHERE (dlin_anoliq <= ?ano2 OR dlin_mesliq < ?mes2)
    GROUP BY dlin_codcli
```

En donde `ano2` es 2019  y `mes2` es 1, ambos son números. La base de datos es `MySQL`.

Comment: Con los datos que has dado lo único que me parece "raro" es que el where este entre parentesis, pero no creo que casque por eso. Podrías subir las tablas o si te da algún error o algo?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Error como tal no da, lo que sucede es que así como esta la consulta, me muesta solamente (por ejemplo) un mes de todos lo que en la tabla hay.

Esa tabla la comence a utilizar en agosto del año 2018, hasta diciembre me daba los datos correctos, me sacaba los meses de agosto a noviembre cuando genere el reporte en diciembre, pero en enero de 2019, no me muestra nada, le hice una pequeña corrección y me de lo dato que comento, de solo un mes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema básicamente es que estás viendo a los campos por separado, y la lógica de comparación que has desarrollado no es correcta.

Usualmente, yo esto lo resuelvo *juntando* los campos, de manera que pueda comparar de una vez el año y el mes, pues la lógica es más directa. Ya que tienes año y mes como números, puedes lograr esto haciendo `año * 100 + mes`, lo que te dará estos resultados:

```
 año mes   año*100+mes
2016  12   201612
2018   1   201801
2018   7   201807
2019   4   201904
```

La ventaja de esto, es que, con los valores obtenidos, puedes utilizar lógica simple para realizar comparaciones: *menor que*, *igual*, *mayor que*, *mayor o igual*, etc.

Adaptando tu consulta, quedaría:

```
SELECT   dlin_codcli, dlin_anoliq, dlin_mesliq
       , SUM(IFNULL(dlin_valint, 0)) AS dlin_valint
  FROM coo_detintaportes
 WHERE dlin_anoliq * 100 + dlin_mesliq < ?ano2 * 100 +  ?mes2
 GROUP BY dlin_codcli
```

Otra posible solución, con la lógica correcta para mantener los campos *separados*, tendría que tomar en cuenta si el año es menor, o el año es igual y el mes es menor o igual, algo así:

```
SELECT   dlin_codcli, dlin_anoliq, dlin_mesliq
       , SUM(IFNULL(dlin_valint, 0)) AS dlin_valint
  FROM coo_detintaportes
 WHERE dlin_anoliq < ?ano2 
    OR (    dlin_anoliq = ?ano2 
        AND dlin_mesliq < ?mes2
       )
 GROUP BY dlin_codcli
```

Comment: jachguate, gracias por la respuesta. Voy a probrar y a jugar un poco con la sugerencia que mes has dato, aunque me parece una mejor opción la primera que das, voy a probrar con la segunda primero, pues al hacer (por encima) la consulta, vi que me dio valores mas ajustados, y digo mas por que me incluia el mes actual, la cambia a solo "<" y me dio. Ahora voy a integrarlo con el resto para analizar si cumple con lo que requiero para el proyecto.

Comment: @AlejandroGarcíaGaray, tienes toda la razón, había incluido hasta el mes actual. Edité la respuesta para incluir hasta el mes anterior al actual. (`<=` vs `<`).

Comment: Bueno amigo, gracias por la respuesta, dio con la solución a mi problema, ahora tengo otro problema pero ya debe ser en otra pregunta, mientras estoy jugando con este código para ver si haciendo unos cambios puedo ajutar toda la consulta en general (el código pasado es parte de una consulta mucho mas amplia. Saludos.